# Take string as input from user by %c and %s and confirm that both the strings are equal

Tags: c, string, strcmp

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main() {  
    char str1[20];
    char *str2;
    printf("enter string \n"); **// using %c  input**
    scanf("%c",str1);
     printf(" string 1  is %s  \n",str1);

  
     printf("enter string 2 \n");
    scanf("%s",*str2); //using %s input
 
     printf(" string 1 and 2 is %c and %s \n",str1,str2);**strong text**

    int a=strcmp(str1,str2); //**comparing both**
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0; 
 }
```

took input from user using %c and %s
then used strcmp for comparing the equality of the strings

Comment: ```scanf("%c",str1)``` will read one char from a keyboard, also you can't assign a string to a ```char *var```. You might want to look for malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `%c` reads one character and doesn't add a terminating null-character, so you have to add that to use the data as string.
- Buffer must be allocated and assigned to `str2` before reading something there.
- `%s` in `scanf()` requires a pointer `char*`, so `str2` should be passed instead of `*str2`.
- `%c` in `printf()` requires `int`, not `char*`, so you have to deference the pointer (automatically converted from the array).

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {  
    char str1[20];
    char *str2;
    printf("enter string \n"); // **using %c  input**
    scanf("%c",str1);
    str1[1] = '\0'; // add terminating null-charachter
    printf(" string 1  is %s  \n",str1);

    str2 = malloc(102400); // allocate buffer
    if (str2 == NULL) return 1; // check if allocation is successful
    printf("enter string 2 \n");
    // pass correct thing
    scanf("%s",str2); //using %s input
 
    printf(" string 1 and 2 is %c and %s \n",*str1,str2); // pass correct thing for %c
    int a=strcmp(str1,str2); //**comparing both**
    printf("%d",a);
    free(str2); // free the allocated buffer
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: enter string
rorr
 string 1  is r
enter string 2
 string 1 and 2 is r and orr
1

Comment: it is not letting me put second string

Comment: @RutvikkWalde `%c` is for reading one character. Enter one-character string for string 1.

Comment: but i want to write a srting /word for both string 1 and string 2

Comment: @RutvikkWalde You should `%s` to read strings, not `%c`.

Comment: @RutvikkWalde: Although you can use `%9c` to read 9 characters, it will read exactly 9 characters, regardless of blanks, newlines, etc. Further, it won't null-terminate the data; you will have a byte array, not a string.  (More accurately, you might accidentally have a string, but that would be because the array already had a null byte at `array[9]` before the input and not because `scanf()` added a null byte.)  So, substantively, the answer to "is there any way to read a string using `%c`?" is "No — not easily or reliably".

Comment: @RutvikkWalde Yes, read characters one-by-one and store them manually in an array. But this looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you stick to `%c`?

Comment: @MikeCAT                                                                                                                      my professor told us this code                                                                                                      #include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main() {  
    char st1[34];
    char st2[34];
    char c;
    int i=0;
    printf("enter string 1 \n");
    scanf("%s",st1);
    printf("enter string 2 \n");
    while(c!='\0'){
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&c);
        st2[i] =c;
        i++;
    }

Comment: st2[i+1]='\0';
    printf("string 1 is %s \n",st1);
    printf("string 2 is %s \n",st2);
    printf("strcmp for these stringsd is %d  \n",strcmp(st1,st2));
    return 0; 
 }

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you please verify the above code

Comment: @RutvikkWalde Your code is wrong. 1. First `while(c!='\0'){` invokes *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized non-static local variable, which is indeteminate. 2. `fflush(stdin);` [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin). 3. `st2[i+1]='\0';` contains off-by-one error.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
char str1[50];
printf("Enter str1:\n");
scanf("%s", str1);   //Using %s input 

char str2[50];
char c;
int i  = 0;
printf("Enter str2:\n");
while(c != '\n')
{
fflush(stdin);  
scanf("%c", &c);  //Using %c input
str2[i] = c;
i++;
}
str2[i-1] = '\0'; 
printf("Str1 is: %s\n", str1);
printf("Str2 is: %s\n", str2);
printf("When comparing str1 and str2 the value it returns is %d", 
strcmp(str1,str2));
return 0;
}
```

NOTE: When giving the input to string 2 enter the values character by character.
for eg:- Enter str2:

- w
- o
- r
- l
- d

And, after you've completed your word, press enter two times.

Comment: You should *really* add some proper indentation to your code. That makes it far more readable.

Comment: I am sorry , I'll remeber it next time.